# Swift, UICollectionView and UINavigationBar top margin issue

Tags: xcode, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uicollectionview

I'm new to Swift and i'm trying to get a full paged gallery in swift using an UICollectionView inside a viewController UINavigationController.

My problem is that i cannot figure out how to get a full paged ImageView with a NavigationBar, what i've got now is this:
[my situation now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vk6o8.png)

but i'd like to have this (with a transparent navigation bar like it is in the first picture):
[what i want to accomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHfAW.png)

I've searched all over the net for many hours, i've tried to:

```
self.collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,0)
```

or

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = true
```

I've also tried to uncheck "Adjusts scroll insets" in Xcode but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two days of searching i've found a solution, in viewController viewDidLoad():

```
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.translucent = true
```

If you don't have a navigationController but only a navigationBar or if you have subclassed UINavigationController:

```
    self.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
    self.navigationBar.translucent = true
```